# How to store timetables?

Tags: database, algorithm

I'm working on a project that must store employees' timetables. For example, one employee works Monday through Thursday from 8am to 2pm and from 4pm to 8pm. Another employee may work Tuesday through Saturday from 6am to 3pm.

I'm looking for an algorithm or a method to store these kind of data in a MySQL database. These data will be rarely accessed so it's not important performance questions.

I've thought to store it as a string but I don't know any algorithm to "encode" and "decode" this string.

Comment: Please don't store it as an "encrypted" string.

Comment: I'm hoping by encrypted you mean pattern.

Comment: Perhaps he means "encode" and "decode"?

Comment: Yes, "encrypted" is encoded :) Changed in the question.. Sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: Please don't store it as an "encoded" string, either.

Comment: @Ivan: My point is that trying to collapse information into a single database field is usually a terrible idea, because you can't index on it effectively, and it becomes very difficult to create sensible `select` queries.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to store this in a single field as a string, as opposed to a table structure with multiple fields?

Comment: It may not be meaningful to store the information in a way in which it can be searched (reading the question, at least). If it just needs to be stored and later displayed, serializing the schedules may make sense. However, I would also lean in the direction of a series of tables if practicable.

Comment: This timetable will be written once and perhaps not changed in years.. It will be readed rarely (once a week or so) and the information stored will be readed, decoded and showed to a human, never will be used for search, edit or similar. That's why I thought that an string will be enough, but if there is a powerful reason to create a couple of tables.. I'll do it. But, still, I have not any idea on how to store it. Which could be a good method to store these data, independently if you prefer to use one row (that was only my first idea) or if you will use a couple of tables?

Comment: It's not very elegant, but I know of experienced programmer/project managers who prefer to store large chunks of data in a database without unpacking them to queryable form. The main reason is organisational: very often changes to database structure have to be explained to and agreed with database management specialists, who are reluctant to change anything - with reason, apparently, because changes take some time and risk leaving us with a broken database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many of the comments indicate, it's usually a poor idea to encode all the data into a string that is basically meaningless to the data base. It's usually better to define the data elements and their relations and represent these structures in the data base. The [Wikipedia article on data models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model) is a good overview of what's involved (although it's way more general than what you need). The problem you are describing seems simple enough that you could do this with pencil and paper.

One way to start is to write down a lists of logical relationships between concepts in your problem. For instance, the list might look like this (your rules may be different):

- Every employee follows a single schedule.
- Every employee has a first and last name, as well as an employee ID. Different employees may have the same name, but each employee's ID is unique to that employee.
- A schedule has a start and stop day of the week and a start and stop time of day.
- The start and stop time is the same for every day of the schedule.
- Several employees may be on the same schedule.

From this, you can list the nouns used in the rules. These are candidates for entities (columns) in the data base:

- Employee
- Employee ID
- Employee first name
- Employee last name
- Schedule
- Schedule start day
- Schedule start time
- Schedule end day
- Schedule end time

For the rules I listed, schedules seem to exist independently of employees. Since there needs be a way of identifying which schedule an employee follows, it makes sense to add one more entity:

- Schedule ID

If you then look at the verbs in the rules ("follows", "has", etc.), you start to get a handle on the relationships. I would group everything so far into two relationships:

```
Employees
    ID
    first_name
    last_name
    schedule_ID

Schedules
    ID
    start_day
    start_time
    end_day
    end_time
```

That seems to be all that's needed by way of data structures. (A reasonable alternative to `start_day` and `end_day` for the Schedules table would be a boolean field for each day of the week.) The next step is to design the indexes. This is driven by the queries you expect to make. You might expect to look up the following:

- What schedule is employee with ID=xyz following?
- Who is at work on Mondays at noon?
- What days have nobody at work?

Since employees and schedules are uniquely identified by their respective IDs, these should be the primary fields of their respective tables. You also probably want to have consistency rules for the data. (For instance, you don't want an employee on a schedule that isn't defined.) This can be handled by defining a "foreign key" relationship between the `Employees.schedule_ID` field and the `Schedules.ID` field, which means that `Employees.schedule_ID` should be indexed. However, since employees can share the same schedule, it should not be a unique index.

If you need to look up schedules by day of week and time of day, those might also be worth indexing. Finally, if you want to look up employees by name, those fields should perhaps be indexed as well.

Comment: Ok, but with this scheme, how do you represent first example ("Monday through Thursday from 8am to 2pm and from 4pm to 8pm"). Start day and end day is ok, but to represent start time and end time I need to use 2 rows in the "Schedules" table, but "Employees" has only one schedule_ID... I'm afraid we need a third table, true?

Comment: Perhaps so. The methodology is the same: start with the set of rules that apply in the domain. Obviously, the rule I used: _"A schedule has a start and stop day of the week and a start and stop time of day."_ does not apply. You just need do the same thing: write down the correct rules, turn the nouns into entities, and use the verbs to define relationships, from which you then form tables. Technical issues such as representing many-to-many relationships may require introducing tables that aren't obvious from the domain description, but that falls out naturally as you work through the process.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using PHP:
Store a timetable in a php array and then use serialize function to transform it in a string;
to get back the array use unserialize. 
However this form of memorization is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Ok, but.. My question is about THE METHOD to store this kind of data. How do you store it in PHP?

Comment: the same way you store strings in a mysql db

Comment: And 50 years of relational algebra have been swept out the window... I won't -1 (for sake of the closing remarks), but relational databases are beautiful things *when used correctly*.

Comment: if the OP ask something, i try to provide an answer and not to escape it; it's clear that i would never implement something this way; but it can be even a good idea in a situation like this in which you don't need to modify data or to perform operations other than reading the timetable